# How to create a Content Type within a Content Type in a SharePoint 2010 list?

Tags: 2010, content-type

[image: Content Type within a Content Type]

How do I create a CT within a CT as shown in the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete James's answer, the lookup is probably used for "linking" the list.

In order to get such display, the easiest and quickest way is to use SPD to create a custom dispform that contains an aggregated data source and a XsltViewWebPArt (I said easy, but it'sz actually a source of headache to understand how this works).

Another way is to create a custome template in 14Hive\controltemplates, and set the parent content type to use this template. Within the template, you can add the "child" view.

A last way (but I don't think it's a good idea to use it), is ti create a custom field type, to implement the display like this.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually add related lists views to list forms directly from the SharePoint UI.

1 - Open a List (e.g. Tasks.

2 - Select the List tab from the Ribbon

3 - In the Customize List Group, select "Default Display Form" from the Modify Form Web Parts menu.

4 - Highlight the main form control (the area around the web part zones)

5 - From the Page Tools > Insert tab, use the Related Lists command from the Relationships group.

Pretty nice - you don't even need SharePoint Designer anymore to add relationship  views to list forms...

Comment: From your screen shot, this  list view has been highly customized (e.g. tabs). The steps I discuss above can be used to show related items, but this is clearly not how they customized the form you have shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there's a lookup to a task list in your image. The Task List has a column of type "Lookup" which connects to the Reservations list, so one reservation can have many tasks.